# How to override a controller using Plugin?

Tags: magento2, overrides, controllers, abstract-class

I want to override abstact class controller `Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder.php` using Plugin.

How can I do that?

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder">
        <plugin name="testing_reorder"
                type="testing\ReorderButton\Plugin\Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\ReorderPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

but I am so new to Magento and looking at documents, I am still confused.

This is the `reorder.php`, I just want to remove a couple lines from this php file which I have marked/commented on below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

/**
 * Abstract class for controllers Reorder(Customer) and Reorder(Guest)
 *
 * @package Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController
 */
abstract class Reorder extends Action\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;


    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                //TO REMOVEEEEE
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
                //END REMOVEEEE
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know we can override the classes with plugin or preferences.

Plugins can be used when you have a piece of code that is supposed to be executed **before, after or around a specific method** in class. This is preferred way wherever possible. But you cannot alter the code in that method. You can read more about plugins from official doc  [Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

In your case you want to alter the code by commenting some lines, so you should use preference not plugins.

Here are the steps to override via preferences.

**app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Controller/AbstractController/Reorder.php**

```
<?php
 
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\AbstractController;
 
class Reorder extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder
{    
    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                //TO REMOVEEEEE
                /*
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
                */
                //END REMOVEEEE
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
?>
```

Hope it was helpful,

Thanks

Comment: Can you actually use preference to override abstract class?